# curved border in css

Tags: css, border

I want to make design css like this
---------------------U-----|
I couldn't draw  exact design here. but the U shape width should be expanded to fit home about links. is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to decipher exactly what you're after just from that description. The text-mode demonstration doesn't really explain it very well :-)

This *could* maybe be achieved using CSS `border-radius`, but if I'm interpreting your request correctly, it sounds like quite a complex layout.

`border-radius` only does rounded corners -- ie the four corners of a box. So if you need more complex layout than that, you'd need to have several boxes with rounded corners, positioned appropriately to get the desired effect.

You may be able to achieve it with just rounded corners on the container box for the home/about links you mentioned. If this doesn't achieve what you need then it sounds to me more like you need a graphic than a CSS border.

If the CSS `border-radius` does work for you, bear in mind that the `border-radius` feature isn't supported on IE. The good news is that there is a hack for IE called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) which fixes that, so you can use `border-radius` in all browsers.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks spudley, yes i dont want ronded corners but i dont know how to

Comment: Thanks spudley, yes i dont want rounded corners but i dont know how to <br> draw that here.. but it'll be like this. The line starts from left to right and after reaching 3/4 th of width it goes down slantly <br> and strightens.. can you imagine?

Comment: hmm, no it's not easy to imagine. Could you create a mock-up graphic and post it somewhere to demonstrate it more clearly? Then edit your original question to link to the demo graphic so we can see it.

Answer (score 2):

http://border-radius.com/ CSS Border Radius Generator

Comment: Ok, but without images, there's no non-CSS3 option for rounded corners

Comment: @Richard and @benhowdle89 -- in fact border-radius can be made to work for *all* browsers, including IE -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it with CSS3 *but* you can use things like [spiffy corners](http://www.spiffycorners.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain compatible with older browsers, then you can't do it in css, you'll have to do it with graphics. IE 8 and below wont do it, not sure about other browsers but bear in mind border radius is quite new.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.test
{
width: 115px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid #000;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
<div class="test">This is some text!</div>
```